# ionic build android's Error : copyFileSync: could not write to dest file

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

When I use the command : `ionic cordova build android` here is what I get :

> cp: copyFileSync: could not write to dest file
>   (code=ENOENT):/Users/mehdigriche/work/cam1/test/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml
>
> Parsing
>   /Users/mehdigriche/work/cam1/test/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml
>   failed (node:2306) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory,
>   open
>   '/Users/mehdigriche/work/cam1/test/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml'
>
> [10:50:14]  lint finished i

Comment: Have you checked the existence of or the permissions on the files mentioned in the error?

Comment: I shouldn't just put this link, but this thread fixed it for me: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2835

Answer (score 22):

Add this hook to cordova project: [patch-android-studio-check.js](https://gist.github.com/joeljeske/68121fa6d643e0937f50458d0172e16e)

1. Put the file ***patch-android-studio-check.js*** in the directory ***hooks*** of your project
2. Add the following lines to the ***config.xml*** of your project:

   ```
   <platform name="android">
       <hook src="hooks/patch-android-studio-check.js" type="before_plugin_install" />
       <hook src="hooks/patch-android-studio-check.js" type="before_plugin_add" />
       <hook src="hooks/patch-android-studio-check.js" type="before_build" />
       <hook src="hooks/patch-android-studio-check.js" type="before_run" />
       <hook src="hooks/patch-android-studio-check.js" type="before_plugin_rm" />
   </platform>
   ```
3. Delete the plugins directory:

   ```
   rm -rf plugins
   ```
4. Reinstall the plugins:

   ```
   ionic build
   ```
5. Reinstall the platform android:

   ```
   cordova platform rm android
   cordova platform add android@latest
   ```

Answer (score 15):

Your command: *ionic cordova build androird* is wrong
I think you means: *ionic cordova build android*

But try also: *ionic cordova build --release android*

I had the same error, after 2 days of debugging I found a solution for me:

in the directory: platforms/android/cordova
I updated in the file Api.js the locations object, because the path are not correct.

current locations object look like this in my Api.js:

```
    this.locations = {
    root: self.root,
    www: path.join(self.root, 'assets/www'),
    res: path.join(self.root, 'res'),
    platformWww: path.join(self.root, 'platform_www'),
    configXml: path.join(self.root, 'app/src/main/res/xml/config.xml'),
    defaultConfigXml: path.join(self.root, 'cordova/defaults.xml'),
    strings: path.join(self.root, 'app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml'),
    manifest: path.join(self.root, 'app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'),
    build: path.join(self.root, 'build'),
    javaSrc: path.join(self.root, 'app/src/main/java/'),
    // NOTE: Due to platformApi spec we need to return relative paths here
    cordovaJs: 'bin/templates/project/assets/www/cordova.js',
    cordovaJsSrc: 'cordova-js-src'
};
```

After these change I was able to build my app.
I had also errors because of plugins like cordova-sqlite-storage so I removed it and build the app.

I hope it helps

Comment: i've tried that but with no success sorry to not mention that everything was ok when i build with ionic 1 everything goes well but when i use ionic 3 it gives me this also this problem is in the platforms folder when i use another folder from an ionic 1 project it fixed

Answer (score 8):

**To solve this problem**

> cp: copyFileSync: could not write to dest file
>   (code=ENOENT):/Users/mehdigriche/work/cam1/test/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml

Create a folder named `xml` in `platforms/android/res`

Answer (score 6):

Apparently, some files are not generated correctly when adding android +7 so, I solved this problem by the following:

Firstly remove your platform,

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
```

then reinstall a lower version (6.3 worked for me )

```
ionic cordova platform add android@6.3.0
```

Comment: @Vivek Android 7+ broke a lot of things, so it's easier to roll back to 6.4.0 for now if your pressed for time and can't find alternative plugins.

Answer (score 5):

I have faced the same issue  this morning and my (rather drastic) solution was this:

1. Remove the platform:

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
```

2. Delete the following folders from your app folder: `platforms`,`plugins` & `www`
3. Make sure your dependencies are available by running: `npm install`
4. Add back the platform, this step will recreate the folders deleted in step 2 above:

```
ionic cordova platform add android
```

5. Finally, build your app:

```
ionic cordova build android
```

Comment: I would keep the "www" folder when you're doing this reset! You may have important asset files in there. :)

Comment: They already present in src folder so no need to worry about that although deleting www will not have any effect @xke

Comment: That depends on your Ionic version - for Ionic v1 projects, you shouldn't delete the 'www' folder!

Answer (score 1):

Note on dtmp's Answer, using the hooks directory seems to be deprecated. Using 'scripts' directory instead might be more appropriate.

When trying to make a build using ionic 2, using a 'hooks' directory lead to the hook js not being found.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the

> Androird

part is just a typo here.

Check this out:
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/13702

It is a known issue and not fixed yet!

Answer (score 0):

If you are like me trying to overcome same issue and try all the way written as solution but not. Try this solution;

1. Open your project folder's `project.json` file.
2. Add this  `"android-versions" : "1.3.0"` dependency.
3. Run npm i.
4. Run command `sudo ionic cordova run android`

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

```
ionic cordova rm platform android
```

remove the www and plugins folder

```
npm cache clean
npm install audit fix
ionic cordova build  android
```

Answer (score 0):

This is too old, but using ionic 4 i have the same problem, i solved it just removing android and adding it again:

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova platform add android
```